# BMI Calculator not showing result

Tags: javascript, html

Cannot make my simple BMI calculator show the actual result, this is the error i get when i enter the web source code.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateBMI is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (bmi:14:2)
```

I tried to fix it with Event Listener, recommended by someone else. Still didnt work and the same result I get. Below is the actual code that im using for the BMI Calculator in Visual Studio Code

```js
// Get a reference to the button element
var calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculateButton');
// Add an event listener to the button
calculateButton.addEventListener('click', calculateBMI);

function calculateBMI() {
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  if (weight && height) {
    var bmi = weight / (height * height);
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('result');
    resultElement.textContent = "Your BMI is " + bmi.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.calculator-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.calculator-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-group label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculate-button {
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-container">
  <h2>Calculator BMI</h2>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="weight">Greutate (kg):</label>
    <input type="number" id="weight" min="0" step="0.1">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="height">Inaltime (cm):</label>
    <input type="number" id="height" min="0" step="1">
  </div>
  <button class="calculate-button" onclick="calculateBMI()">Calculeaza BMI</button>
  <div class="result" id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the inline click
2. Use the correct id. The button did not have an ID
3. You need the height in meters
4. Wrap the assignment of the event listener in a load event

```js
function calculateBMI() {
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  if (weight && height) {
    height /= 100; // meters
    var bmi = weight / (height * height);
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('result');
    resultElement.textContent = "Your BMI is " + bmi.toFixed(2);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when the page has loaded the elements
  // Get a reference to the button element
  var calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculateButton');
  // Add an event listener to the button
  calculateButton.addEventListener('click', calculateBMI);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.calculator-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.calculator-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-group label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculate-button {
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-container">
  <h2>Calculator BMI</h2>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="weight">Greutate (kg):</label>
    <input type="number" id="weight" min="0" step="0.1">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="height">Inaltime (cm):</label>
    <input type="number" id="height" min="0" step="1">
  </div>
  <button class="calculate-button" id="calculateButton">Calculeaza BMI</button>
  <div class="result" id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Result in latest Chrome

[image]

Comment: No more errors showing up in the console, the result however still wont show up for some reason. I tried disabling all extension in case they interfere with it and I tried to run the calculator on a different browser and I still cannot see the answer to the calculation.

Comment: Did you run it here? You have to scroll down to see it due to YOUR CSS

Comment: I ran it here and it works, tried running it from vscode, apparently it only works when opening the HTML with a Live server.

Comment: Did you put the script UNDER the HTML? If not then wrap the script in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { ... your code here ... });` See updated script